# find files not referenced by project vs 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to find all files in project's root folder or subfloders which are not referenced by this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing automated - in the Solution Explorer you can select the project node and click on the `Show All Files` button.

You will then see files and folders not referenced by the project as grayed out.

If you wanted to automate this, you could produce a list of all files in the project directory and subdirectories from the OS (using `dir` and redirecting the output to a file, for instance) and parse the project file to get a list of all files referenced by it. At this point, it would be a matter of comparing both lists.

Comment: 'Show All Files' is exactly what I need. Thank you!